# How to get values of multiple textboxes generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have a button called 'AddTextArea', on clicking, I get new text area, but how can I get the values that I have entered in the new text areas?

I tried like this-

```
var x= document.getElementById("div_quotes").value;
```

but it's not working.
Please help, as I am new to JS, thanks in advance.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTextArea(){
            var div = document.getElementById('div_quotes');
            div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote[]' />";
            div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <!--<input type="text" name="text_new_author" /><br />-->
    <div id="div_quotes"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
    <input type="submit" name="submitted">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('textarea[name="new_quote[]"]');` But I'd advice to use a class instead: `div.innerHTML += "<textarea class="myTextArea"' />";` and `document.querySelectorAll('.myTextArea');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x= document.getElementById("div_quotes").value;
```

Above code will not work as `div_quotes` is a div and `div` do not have `value` property.

You will have to search for textareas in this div.

**Sample**

```js
function addTextArea() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div_quotes');
  div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote[]' />";
  div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
}

function validate(){
  var tas = document.querySelectorAll('#div_quotes  textarea[name="new_quote[]"]')  
  for(var i = 0; i< tas.length; i++){
    console.log(tas[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <!--<input type="text" name="text_new_author" /><br />-->
  <div id="div_quotes"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
  <input type="button" name="submitted" onclick="validate()" value="Validate"> 
</form>
```

---

**Version 2**

Now if you notice in above sample, if you type and then add another textarea, it will flush value of previous  ones. This is because, you are setting `.innerHTML += ...`. This will destroy and recreate all elements again. You should use `document.createElement`

```js
function addTextArea() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div_quotes');
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div')
  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
  ta.name = "new_quote[]"
  wrapper.append(ta);
  div.append(wrapper)
}

function validate(){
  var tas = document.querySelectorAll('#div_quotes  textarea[name="new_quote[]"]')  
  for(var i = 0; i< tas.length; i++){
    console.log(tas[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <!--<input type="text" name="text_new_author" /><br />-->
  <div id="div_quotes"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
  <input type="button" name="submitted" onclick="validate()" value="Validate"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS Class to the new text area that is generated and get the data using

```html
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicTxtArea")
```

I have added the class to the Text area that is being dynamically generated. Please check the code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTextArea(){
            div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote[]' class='dynamicTxtArea'/>";
            div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <!--<input type="text" name="text_new_author" /><br />-->
    <div id="div_quotes"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
    <input type="submit" name="submitted">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```